# Is there anything I can do so this does not happen to anyone else?

Tags: professionalism, working-conditions

I had a really good job of 13 years; I was a biller for 10 years and then when they sold the company, they dissolved my department.  I was the only employee in my department the new company kept. I never had a new job title because I wore so many different hats; they never knew what title to give me. They allowed all of us who stayed to keep our seniority and I had a 401k that I was fully vested and I had 3 weeks vacation.  The only downside was it was far away (40 miles round trip each day) and I was working 12 hour days sometimes 6 days a week.

I put my resume out there to see what my options were.  I was offered a job making $1.50 more an hour only 6 miles from my house. I would be losing a week vacation and would be doing billing again.

The new job assured me that in 90 days I would have paid holidays, vacations and said they would work with me and my schedule.  I was to work from 7:30am to 4:30pm which was great.

I later found out that I was put in a very hostile environment that had nothing to do with me, and I never wanted to be a part of.

I was told to be there at 7:45 for my first day. Monday morning I arrived at 7:30 and the hiring manager just looked at me like she was mad that I was 15 minutes early.  She walked me over to my team, never introduced me to anyone, and said, "this is your lead, keep track of your hours today till I get you in the system". The lead girl showed me to my desk, and I went to put my purse away and the drawer of my desk fell apart. When I was looking around my desk, I found I had no stapler, no pen, pencil, paper, post-its, not even a trash can. I had a tiny little monitor and when I looked around the office everyone had two monitors. When I asked where to get supplies to do my job, I was told they would show me later.  When I asked for a second monitor to help me do the job I was told they stole theirs from someone on the other side of the building.. I then asked if I could bring one from home? They said "**absolutely not**".

Well, the girl training me had put in her notice and did not want to train me at all. She never explained their system at all, just told me to click here and click there and sent me on my way.  Then they told me I had to stay until 5pm and they all left at 4:00pm and I was all by myself for the last hour and had no idea what to do.

I decided to go back the second day, and to bring my own paper, post-its, paper clips, etc. so I could at least take notes. Needless to say, it was a toxic environment, and I was put in something I did not want to be any part of. I was the only who did not speak Spanish and they were all talking behind my back. I know some Spanish and what they were saying was not nice. I did not go back the next day.

This is not okay with me, I walked away from something that was good, thinking that this was going to be better. Lesson learned but, I don't want this to happen to someone else, and to be honest I am now unemployed, and my life is now upside down.  I never had a chance, and feel they were dishonest and should not be able to this to people.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: spread more widely the adage "the grass is always greener on the other side?"

Comment: leave review on glassdoor (knowing its only sorta anonymous)

Comment: There's lots you _can_ do. Some of it might even be legal and/or ethical - but honestly it sounds like the most important thing for you to do is to concentrate your efforts on finding another job rather than worrying about this one. Also, phone up your old boss and see if there's any chance your old job is still open.

Comment: "The only downfall was it was so far away (40 miles round trip each day) and I was working 12 hour days sometimes 6 days a week."  Other one doesn't seem much better from my perspective, maybe this is a good chance to look for another option (though maybe its a cultural difference)

Comment: In what country?

Comment: Is there a specific thing you want to prevent your previous employer from doing? The only explicit lie here might be about your hours (leaving at 5pm instead of 4:30pm). This mostly sounds like them being bad at onboarding new employees. As for *"...what they were saying was not nice..."*, it'd have to be pretty awful for it to be actionable.

Comment: The original version of this question was extremely wordy and full of information that was irrelevant.  I cut it down to be more easily readable.

Answer (score 9):

I’d recommend calling your old company first thing in the morning and see if you can get your old job back. Obviously only if you are willing to go back. Hard to say what your chances are, but even a one in ten chance is worth a phone call.

Comment: Good advice but it doesn't answer the "Is there anything I can do so this does not happen to anyone else?" question.

Answer (score 7):

This very much depends on your locale and industry.  I don't know much about "billing" (I don't even know what "billing" is, is that like "accounts receivable"?) and you didn't add a region tag so it's hard to answer.

For my own profession, as a software engineer in North America, there is a website called Glassdoor where people can leave (semi-)anonymous reviews of companies and stories about their work experiences there.  If Glassdoor is something used in your field or your locale, you can leave a review there, or you can find out what similar websites exist for your field/locale.  I do know that Glassdoor gets used quite heavily, as I use it myself whenever I begin a new job search, to investigate new companies and see if they're legit.

That said, if you're going to leave a review on Glassdoor or elsewhere, please spellcheck and grammar-check your review and make your story concise.  Nobody is going to read a review that reads like a wall of text with a bunch of spelling/grammar errors, they're just going to assume you are of below-average intelligence and were fired as such, and you hold a meaningless grudge; you won't be taken seriously.  I edited your question to make it read better, but if I had seen your original question as a review on Glassdoor that is what I would have assumed.  Be careful with what and how you write; if you don't present yourself as a serious person then you will not be taken seriously.

Answer (score 3):

There's little you can do to stop this happening to anyone else, but you can stop this happening to yourself in future.

When you apply and interview for a position, ask lots of questions about the work environment. For example ask in interview to see where you'll be working. Also state before starting any conditions you have such as dual monitors.

There's nothing wrong with stating your own demands, it makes clear you're serious about your work and also if a company does reject you on that basis then it is clear there is a culture clash.

Interviews aren't just for the employer to vet the candidate, it's also an opportunity for the candidate to vet the employer.

Comment: @Kcalderon, Also, ask to view the work area. And if you're only being interviewed by a manager, ask to speak to your future colleagues. Interviewing is a skill. It takes time and practice to develop that skill.